# How To Write a Section/Part/Chapter Title with Words from Multiple Languages in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I have been looking for an answer to this for a while. To clarify what I want just in case my question title might seem ambiguous:

```
\section{Привет and Xin Chào!}
Some text...
```

I am using the *babel* package to use different languages in my paragraphs and I thought I could use the commands inside `\section{}` but it didn't work. Commands such as these:

```
\selectlanguage{language}
\begin{otherlanguage}{language} text \end{otherlanguage}
```

I also tried declaring a variable for the particular section title like this:

```
\newcommand{\multiLangSectionTitle}{
 \selectlanguage{russian}
  Привет 
     \begin{otherlanguage}{vietnam} 
      and Xin Chào 
     \end{otherlanguage}
}
```

Thinking that it will act like as a unit when I do `\section{\multiLangSectionTitle}` but it didn't work either.

Any ideas welcome. Many thanks for your help!
LD

Comment: You might try asking this on http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please clarify "does not work". babel will switch input shorthands (like "o for ö) which will not work if \selectlanguage is itself in the argument to another command, and the static name of the table of contents and things like that which do not apply here. It also switches hyphenation patterns, but section titles are usually not hyphenated anyway.

Comment: It returned a compiling error. Actually, \selectlanguage does actually work as an argument for another command as the command \multiLangSectionTitle that I wrote above still works in paragraphs. It's just when I put it inside \section{}, it wouldn't compile. But as Frederik hinted, I'll have a look at XeTeX. Thanks for help and for your suggestion on visiting tex.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use xetex and write everything in utf-8. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XeTeX
Works perfect for me, combining the three japanese alphabets and swedish.